# React Native - Detect Physically Broken Screen

Tags: react-native, screen

Im trying to develop an app in react native that can detect if the screen of the user is physically broken. It's for an insurance company that wants to check if someone's phone isn't already broken when they insure it.

Obviously I can just ask the user to take a picture of the phone pointing at a mirror and validate it my self.

But instead, i've been wondering if even such technology exists or maybe there is work around for the matter. Probably painting the entire screen to detect pixel by pixel if any is broken but I don't know how to do that or what to use.

If anyone knows if a way exists I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR- No.

Not only in react native, even in native android or ios api there is no such thing to check screen damage.

As far as your app is concerned, user involvement is necessary to detect screen or touch damage.

Just display different colors on screen and ask user to check for any discoloration or “dead” pixels.

And for touch, ask user to tap different parts of screen or drag finger accross and check for touch misses or bad areas.
There are some good touch testing apps available on the play store, give them a shot.